# creating a trigger based on time after one year in mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

My database has two tables: `plans` and `status`. `plans` has an attibute `issue_date`.

I want to create a trigger such that when the `issue_date` crosses one year, the attibute status in the `status` table should become inactive.

Comment: A database trigger is normally activated by an event - and `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. And then, it will only act on the rows that were changed. This would seem more like something that should run as a nightly job.

Comment: Looking at your set-up in more detail, it seems a bit odd. Why would the `status` of a plan not be stored in `plans`? This reads like for every record in the `plans` table, you've got one and only one corresponding record in `status`. Is that correct? Or is `status` a table listing the possible statuses, with `plans` having a foreign key column that points to the appropriate `status`?

Comment: Yes,there is a status table which consists of all the active and inactive plans of customers. The plan table is connected with the help of a foreign key to the status table.

Comment: Are you sure that's not the other way around? If many `plan`s all tie to one `status`, then you could have a plan that's just over a year old, and another plan that's two months old, and you'd set the status to inactive. Or, do you mean that `status` should be set to inactive when *all* `plan` rows tied to a `status` are more than one year past the `issue_date`?

Answer (score 1):

Triggers only occur when an action (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`) occurs, but that's not the case here.

You have a record which has "aged out". So, basically, it just sits there and does nothing unless you actively "look for it"! The server can only react to what it can perceive as a change - not an arbitrary record age!

You'll have to use `events` - say (in your case), fired once a day! Think of these as "temporal programmable triggers".

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html), the first thing you do is (one of):

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

That sets the events `daemon` (or `service` on Windows), which are like a `cron job` or an `at`) in motion ([see](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html)), so basically now, events will be fired.

Then, from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/) do something like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE 
    EVENT `entity_update` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-10-20 03:00:00'  -- do this at three in the morning! 
    DO BEGIN    

      -- This is where to put the SQL below - I forgot about 
      -- the non-standards-compliant dialect of SQL that 
      -- MySQL uses (see comparison with PostgreSQL below!).

    END */$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Be sure and test a couple of times before you "bed" your solution in!

The update SQL would look something like this (made a guess at table structure based on OP - see full `DDL` and `DML` below)

```
UPDATE status
SET status.status_plan = 'inactive'
WHERE status.status_plan_id IN
(
  SELECT del_id 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT s.status_plan_id AS del_id
    FROM plan p
    JOIN status s
    ON p.plan_id = s.status_plan_id
    WHERE p.plan_issue_date < (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) -- plan_issue_date older than 1 year
    AND s.status_plan = 'active'  -- <-- and only change those which are not already inactive!
  ) AS things_to_delete
);
```

Incredibly, for [reasons outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause), with MySQL, we programmers have to put in an artificial sub`SELECT` into our `UPDATE`! Check out the much simpler and more elegant PostgreSQL syntax below:

```
UPDATE status
SET status_plan = 'inactive'
WHERE status.status_plan_id IN
(
  SELECT s.status_plan_id
  FROM plan p
  JOIN status s
  ON p.plan_id = s.status_plan_id
  WHERE p.plan_issue_date < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 YEAR'
  AND s.status_plan = 'active'  -- <-- only change those which are not already inactive!
);
```

(Full MySQL solution [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7erGqDDgD53jXr9Nb39NV8/0), PostgreSQL [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXNvabkxqMYRQtyUEjsduz/0))

---------- MySQL DDL ---------

```
CREATE TABLE plan 
(
  plan_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  plan_issue_date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE status 
(
  status_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  status_plan_id INTEGER,
  status_plan VARCHAR (10),  -- no CHECK CONSTRAINTs in MySQL!
  CONSTRAINT status_plan_fk FOREIGN KEY (status_plan_id) REFERENCES plan (plan_id) 
);
```

**Incredibly**, MySQL does **not** support `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s on tables! You can get around this in three (clumsy IMHO) ways:

- `TRIGGER`s - as outlined - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248038/470530). Very clumsy - these should be for complex business logic and not for relatively simple criteria - [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) and all that!
- A small lookup/reference table - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522635/470530). Not a bad alternative, but not the most elegant - I prefer, if possible, to keep all definitions/constraints associated with a table in the `CREATE TABLE` statement!
- `VIEW`s with [CHECK OPTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-check-option.html) - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42761859/470530). Quite why MySQL can provide `VIEW`s with such an option but not tables is beyond me!

`<rant over...>`

------------ DDL for both MySQL and PostgreSQL ------------

```
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (35, 1, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (45, 2, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (67, 3, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (78, 4, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (95, 5, 'inactive');


INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (35, 1, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (45, 2, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (67, 3, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (78, 4, 'active');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_plan_id, status_plan) VALUES (95, 5, 'inactive');
```

------------------ PostgreSQL DDL ----------------------------------

```
CREATE TABLE plan
(
  plan_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT plan_pk PRIMARY KEY (plan_id),
  plan_issue_date DATE -- , CONSTRAINT plan_date_ct_gt_now CHECK (plan_issue_date > NOW())
                       --   might be an idea for future inserts into plan? 
);
ALTER SEQUENCE plan_plan_id_seq RENAME TO plan_seq;

INSERT INTO plan (plan_issue_date) VALUES ('2017-10-15');
INSERT INTO plan (plan_issue_date) VALUES ('2016-10-15');  -- << older than 1 year
INSERT INTO plan (plan_issue_date) VALUES ('2017-07-23');
INSERT INTO plan (plan_issue_date) VALUES ('2016-03-04');  -- << older than 1 year
INSERT INTO plan (plan_issue_date) VALUES ('2016-02-25');  -- <<= older than 1 year and inactive in status table.

CREATE TABLE status 
(
  status_id SERIAL, 
  CONSTRAINT status_pk PRIMARY KEY (status_id),
  status_plan_id INTEGER, 
  status_plan VARCHAR(10) CHECK (status_plan IN ('active', 'inactive')),
  CONSTRAINT status_plan_fk FOREIGN KEY (status_plan_id) REFERENCES plan (plan_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, filter 'old' items as you read from the table.

Or... A Virtual Computed Column that is a true/false value based on the date in another column.  (A Persistent Computed Column would not work.)

Comment: This can work well if the `status` is Boolean, and based solely on the date. If there are multiple possible values, then explicitly setting status to "Inactive" may make more sense that having to override its current value. It's not clear if this is equivalent to a "delete" flag or not; queries may return "inactive" records. Also: works OK if all user access is through an application, less well if users can query the table directly (as all users need to know to do this. A view or a computed column can resolve the user issue.

Comment: You could do this as a `VIEW` also. But, given the question, I think it's an actual concrete change in the data and as such should be reflected as such in the base table! Just IMHO and YMMV! :-). I don't think that systems should have more objects (tables, fields, views... &c.) than they require - [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Comment: "Concrete" -- See "virtual" versus "persistent".

Comment: Hmmm... come to think of it, you're perhaps correct! Using an event might be a clumsy approach. If you're going to keep a record in the table anyway, perhaps a virtual column might be the answer! But maybe the OP doesn't have the CREATE/ALTER TABLE privilege? Or is not on the latest version of MySQL? That happens frequently enough (often amazes me!). But a `GENERATED BY` (or `CALCULATED` or `COMPUTED BY` or whatever) VIRTUAL column would also be solution!